# Attached file is not showing in the document

Tags: acumatica

I have a requirement to generate file while saving Purchase order to upload to a ftp and save the file as a attachment as a text file in file section

I am generating the file in RowPersisted Event

```
protected void POOrder_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted InvokeBaseHandler)
{
    if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
        InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
    var row = (POOrder)e.Row;
    if (e.TranStatus == PXTranStatus.Open)
    {
        if (row.Hold != true && row.Status == POOrderStatus.Open)
        {
            string output = GenerateFeed();  // Generates Feed and upload to Ftp.
            AttachFile(row, output);
        }
    }
}


private void  AttachFile(POOrder row , string output)
{
    string filename = $"{row.OrderNbr.ToString()}.txt";
    byte[] data = output.ToByteArray();
    PX.SM.UploadFileMaintenance filegraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.SM.UploadFileMaintenance>();
    PX.SM.FileInfo fileinfo = new PX.SM.FileInfo(filename, null, data);
    if (filegraph.SaveFile(fileinfo, PX.SM.FileExistsAction.CreateVersion))
    {
        PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(Base.Document.Cache, row, new Guid[] { fileinfo.UID.Value });
        string note = PXNoteAttribute.GetNote(Base.Document.Cache, row);
        PXNoteAttribute.SetNote(Base.Document.Cache, row, note);
    }
}
```

The attached file is not available in the file menu of the document.

After checking, I have found the link is not created in NoteDoc.

Anybody having solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have overridden Persist and generating the feed and also attaching the file to document.

I have faced one issue here is the method called so many times and feed generated and each execution and added a new version into the file system

I am controlling the file generation through an unbounded field created as an extension on POOrder DAC

```
public delegate Int32 PersistDelegate(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation);
    [PXOverride]
    public Int32 Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation, PersistDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        var row = Base.Document.Current;
        POOrderExt ext = Base.Document.Cache.GetExtension<POOrderExt>(row);
        if (row.Hold != true && row.Status == POOrderStatus.Open && Base.Document.Cache.GetStatus(Base.Document.Current) != PXEntryStatus.Inserted)
        {
            if (ext.UsrIsProcessed == null && (operation == PXDBOperation.Delete || operation == PXDBOperation.Update))
            {
                ext.UsrIsProcessed = true;
                string output = GenerateFeed();
                AttachFile(row, output);
            }
        }

        return baseMethod(cacheType, operation);
    }
```

**DAC Extension**

```
    public class POOrderExt : PXCacheExtension<POOrder>
    {
        #region UsrIsProcessed
        [PXBool]
        public virtual bool? UsrIsProcessed { get; set; }
        public abstract class usrIsProcessed : IBqlField { }
        #endregion
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that after POOrder row has been persisted it's too late to modify it because it won't be persisted again. You're likely attaching the file properly but not saving the POOrder record after the file is attached.

You can modify POOrder in RowPersisted but you can't persist it again without causing an infinite loop.

You need to modify and persist POOrder to attach the file so I suggest hooking RowPersisting instead of RowPersisted:

```
void POOrder_RowPersisting(PXCache cache, 
                           PXRowPersistingEventArgs e, 
                           PXRowPersisting del)
```

This will take care of the saving issues because Persisting is called just before Persisted actually persist the change to POOrder. To attach the file you only need to call SetFileNotes:

```
if (filegraph.SaveFile(fileinfo, PX.SM.FileExistsAction.CreateVersion))
{
    PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(Base.Document.Cache, row, fileinfo.UID.Value);
}
```

[image]